# android : Badge not remove from calendar

Tags: android, badge

I am creating calendar which contains events and I want to show total no of events on particular date. I am using 
CalendarAdapter.java class. For showing total no. of events count (like notification bubble) on date I am using
Badge.java class. Now problem is that badge is apply on Calendars dates which current month is showing first, 
after changing month then that badge is not remove from next month calendar.

Calendar Adapter:

```
package vyClean.wemecalendar.adapters;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import vyClean.wemecalendar.activity.Event1;
import vyClean.wemecalendar.util.BadgeView;
import vyClean.wemecalendar.util.BadgeView1;
import vyClean.wemecalendar.util.CalendarEvent;
import vyClean.wemecalendar.R;
import vyClean.wemecalendar.util.ToastMessage;

public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonth;

/*-----------calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view-------------------*/


    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int mnthlength;

    String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;
    public static TextView textno;
    RelativeLayout cal_item_ll;
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> day_string;
    private View previousView;
    private View getView;
    public ArrayList<CalendarEvent> event_calendar_arr;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context context, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar, ArrayList<CalendarEvent> event_calendar_arr) {

        this.event_calendar_arr = event_calendar_arr;
        CalendarAdapter.day_string = new ArrayList<>();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.getDefault());
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        this.context = context;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();

    }

    public int getCount() {

        return day_string.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return day_string.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        getView = convertView;
        TextView dayView;

        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            getView = vi.inflate(R.layout.cal_item, parent, false);
            cal_item_ll = (RelativeLayout) getView.findViewById(R.id.cal_item_ll);
            //textno = (TextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.textno);
        }

        dayView = (TextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        String[] separatedTime = day_string.get(position).split("-");
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");

        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {

            dayView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);

        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {

            dayView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);

        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff69b4"));
        }
        if (day_string.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {

            getView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        } else {
            getView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }

        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = day_string.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }

        int len = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.size();
        HashSet<String> eventListSet1 = new HashSet<>();

        int flag = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            //textno.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            CalendarEvent cal_event = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.get(j);

            if (day_string.get(position).equals(cal_event.getEventFromDate())) {
                eventListSet1.add(cal_event.getEventCateId());
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            setEventView(getView, position, dayView, eventListSet1);
           /*----------call badgeview here--------*/
            /*----------call badgeview on linear layout (cal_item_ll) which is inside getview--------*/
            BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(context, cal_item_ll);
            badge.setText("1");
            badge.show();

        }
        System.out.println("eventListSet1:" + eventListSet1);
        return getView;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view, int pos) {

        if (previousView != null) {

            // previousView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            previousView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }

        view = previousView;
        // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        int len = day_string.size();
        if (len > pos) {
            if (day_string.get(pos).equals(curentDateString)) {

            } else {

                previousView = view;
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {

        // clear items
        items.clear();
        day_string.clear();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.getDefault());

        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        //Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three month's (previous,current,next) dates.
        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        //setting the start date as previous month's required date.
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);
        // filling calendar gridview.
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            System.out.println(" 214 itemvale :" + itemvalue);
            day_string.add(itemvalue);

        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

    public void setEventView(View v, int pos, TextView txt, HashSet<String> eventListSet1) {

        ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
        int len = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            CalendarEvent cal_event = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.get(i);
            int len1 = day_string.size();

            if (len1 > pos) {

                String category = cal_event.getEventCateId();
                HashSet<String> eventListSet = new HashSet<String>();
                StringTokenizer stR = new StringTokenizer(category, ",");

                while (stR.hasMoreTokens()) {

                    eventListSet.add(stR.nextToken());
                }

                ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList(eventListSet1);
                Collections.sort(sortedList);
                //System.out.println("sortedList:" + sortedList);
                StringBuffer CategoryNew = new StringBuffer();
                Iterator<String> itr = sortedList.iterator();

                while (itr.hasNext()) {

                    CategoryNew.append(itr.next() + ",");
                }

                eventList.add(category);

                switch (CategoryNew.toString()) {
                   /* ----------only one category ----------*/

                    case "1,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gs);
                        break;
                    case "2,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.se);
                        break;
                    case "3,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ge);
                        break;
                    case "4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tuce);
                        break;
                    /*----------two category----------*/

                    case "1,2,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gsse);
                        break;
                    case "1,3,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gsge);
                        break;
                    case "1,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gstuce);
                        break;
                    case "2,3,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sege);
                        break;
                    case "2,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.setuce);
                        break;
                    case "3,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.getuce);
                        break;
                    /*----------three category----------*/

                    case "1,2,3,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gssege);
                        break;
                    case "1,3,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gsgetuce);
                        break;
                    case "1,2,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gssetuce);
                        break;
                    case "2,3,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gesetuce);
                        break;
                    /*----------four category----------*/

                    case "1,2,3,4,":
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gssegetuce);

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid event");
                        break;
                }
                /*BadgeView1 badge = new BadgeView1(context, cal_item_ll);
                badge.setText("1");
                badge.show();*/

                txt.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            }
        }

    }

    public void getPositionList(String date, final Activity act) {

        final String TAG_EVENT_NAME = "event_name";
        final String TAG_EVENT_DESC = "event_desc";
        final String TAG_EVENT_FROM_DATE = "event_from_date";
        final String TAG_EVENT_TO_DATE = "event_to_date";
        final String TAG_EVENT_TIMING = "event_timing";
        final String TAG_EVENT_PLACE = "event_place";
        final String TAG_EVENT_CATE_ID = "event_cate_id";

        String event_name, event_desc, event_from_date;
        String event_to_date, event_timing, event_place, event_cate_id;

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> event = new ArrayList<>();

        int len = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.size();


        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            CalendarEvent cal_event = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.get(i);

            event_name = cal_event.getEventName();
            event_desc = cal_event.getEventDesc();
            event_from_date = cal_event.getEventFromDate();
            event_to_date = cal_event.getEventToDate();
            event_timing = cal_event.getEventTiming();
            event_place = cal_event.getEventPlace();
            event_cate_id = cal_event.getEventCateId();

            if (date.equals(event_from_date)) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                map.put(TAG_EVENT_NAME, event_name);
                map.put(TAG_EVENT_DESC, event_desc);
                map.put(TAG_EVENT_FROM_DATE, event_from_date);
                map.put(TAG_EVENT_TO_DATE, event_to_date);
                map.put(TAG_EVENT_TIMING, event_timing);
                map.put(TAG_EVENT_PLACE, event_place);

                if (event_cate_id.equals(1)) {
                    map.put(TAG_EVENT_CATE_ID, "General Science");
                }
                if (event_cate_id.equals(2)) {
                    map.put(TAG_EVENT_CATE_ID, "Scientific Exhibition");
                }
                if (event_cate_id.equals(3)) {
                    map.put(TAG_EVENT_CATE_ID, "General Events");
                }
                if (event_cate_id.equals(4)) {
                    map.put(TAG_EVENT_CATE_ID, "Tuce Clubs");
                }
                if (event_cate_id.equals("")) {
                    map.put(TAG_EVENT_CATE_ID, "");
                }

                event.add(map);
            }
        }
        if (event.size() > 0) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("EVENT_LIST", event);
            Intent in = new Intent(context, Event1.class);
            in.putExtras(b);
            context.startActivity(in);
        } else {
            ToastMessage.toastMessage(context, "On this date there is no event");
        }

    }
```

BadgeView.class -

```
package vyClean.wemecalendar.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BadgeView extends TextView {

    private Context context;
    protected View target;
    private ShapeDrawable badgeBg;

    public BadgeView(Context context, View target) {

        this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, target);
    }

    public BadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, View target) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, target);
    }

    private void init(Context context, View target) {
        try {


            this.context = context;
            this.target = target;

            //apply defaults
            setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            setPadding(7, 0, 7, 0);
            setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            if (this.target != null) {
                applyTo(this.target);
            } else {
                show();
            }
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void applyTo(View target) {

        try {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = target.getLayoutParams();
            //ViewParent parent =  target.getParent();
            FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(context);

            // TODO verify that parent is indeed a ViewGroup
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) target;
            int index = group.indexOfChild(target);

            group.removeView(target);
            group.addView(container, index,lp);
            container.addView(target);
            container.addView(this);
            group.invalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        try {
            if (getBackground() == null) {
                if (badgeBg == null) {
                    badgeBg = getDefaultBackground();
                }
                setBackgroundDrawable(badgeBg);
            }
            applyLayoutParams();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ShapeDrawable getDefaultBackground() {
        ShapeDrawable drawable = null;
        try {
            float[] outerR = new float[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20};
            RoundRectShape rr = new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null);
            drawable = new ShapeDrawable(rr);
            drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    private void applyLayoutParams() {
        try {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
           setLayoutParams(lp);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```